# If a CPU says "supports ddr4 2100" buit my motherboard can overclock my ram, will that even work?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I'm buying an MSI X99A motherboard.

Only two CPUs support it though, the i7 5820 and 5930.

Both of the processors say "Supports ddr4 2100"

I bought ddr4 3000 RAM and the motherboard says

> Memory: 8x DDR4-3333(OC)/ 3110(OC)/ 3000(OC)/ 2750(OC)/ 2666(OC)/ 2600(OC)/ 2400(OC)/ 2200(OC)/ 2133 DIMM Slots,Quad-Channel, Non-ECC, Unbuffered,Max Capacity up to 128GB

So i can overclock instead of wasting money on ddr4 3000 ram right?

Comment: You can clock the RAM at 2100 and you will still get the benefits of the faster RAM in the form of fewer wait states.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine.  Although I don't think you need to overclock the RAM.  If its meant to run at 3000Mhz you should be able to drop it into the motherboard, make sure your settings in BIOS will allow it to run at 3000Mhz, and go from there.  I don't recommend going past 3000Mhz on your RAM as it may make your system unstable.

For example, I have an AMD A10-7850k CPU that (according to Amazon) supports 2133Mhz DDR3 RAM.  My motherboard is an Asus Crossblade Ranger that supports DDR3 1333Mhz to 2666Mhz.  I'm currently using 16Gb of 2400Mhz RAM and I have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your motherboard supports it(which, as an enthusiast-class product, it should), you can overclock the memory controller to run the RAM at its highest supported speed by enabling the appropriate XMP profile in the BIOS.